# VB.net Array throwing an exception

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop

The following sub is throwing a

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

exception.

```
For Each element As Song In modFiles.getSongs()
    Dim col(2) As String
    Dim item As ListViewItem
    col(0) = element.SongTitle
    col(1) = element.PlayTime
    col(2) = element.SongFilename
    item = New ListViewItem(col)
    setList.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

The exception is thrown on lines

```
col(0) = element.SongTitle
col(1) = element.PlayTime
col(2) = element.SongFilename
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

[Your array declaration is fine.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)

Your `For Each` iterator is returning a null object somewhere. Wrap a null test around the body of the loop.

```
For Each element As Song In modFiles.getSongs()
    If element IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim col(2) As String
        Dim item As ListViewItem
        col(0) = element.SongTitle
        col(1) = element.PlayTime
        col(2) = element.SongFilename
        item = New ListViewItem(col)
        setList.Items.Add(item)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot one element in your array

```
Dim col(3) As String
```

Comment: Arrays are 0 bound, col(2) has three items.